# Get Document Field from Next Document

Tags: lotus-domino

I currently have a form set up in Domino Designer with a computed value button that links to the next document when clicked: `<a href=\"./" + @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) + "?Navigate&To=Next\" \">`

What I would like to do is make the button only link to the next document if the next document's form field "Product_Category" is null/empty.

I have tried `@GetDocField` but can't find out how to get the UNID of the next document in the list. Then I found DbLoopup but not really sure how to get that to work either. See my current code below.

```
@DbLookup("";"Server":"Database.nsf";"v-productbycategory";"Product_Category");
```

The forms are listed in a view named 'Products\by Category' with an alias 'v-productbycategory' and sorted by 'Product_Category' then 'Product_Code'.

Would really appreciate any help or please tell me if this is not possible or more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument from your @DbLookup. There should be a key value in between the view name and the name of the field you are returning. But I'm having trouble understanding how you think an @DbLookup will help you find the next document. What's your key going to be? Is it the current document's Product_Category? If it is, you won't return documents with blank Product_Category. If your key is blank, there's no relationship of the returned documents to the current document.

It seems to me that you probably want to be using @DbColumn to get a complete listing of the @DocumentUniqueIDs in the view, then scan the result list for the current document's @DocumentUniqueID, and then use @GetDocField to retrieve the Product_Category field fpr the next @DocumentUniqueId in the list and check if it is blank.

P.S. You'll need to add a column containing @DocumentUniqueID to your view if it's not already there, or probably @Text(@GetDocumentUniqueID)). If this is a visible view and you don't want that column there, you'll need to add a hidden view in the same sort order but with that column.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I wasn't sure that @DbLookup would help but it was the closest thing I could find at the time. Just trying to get your proposal to work.